# Arrays y Tablas HTML¿Porque la tabla no me sale como es?

Tags: php, html

**Hola mi problema es que estoy utilizando arrays multidimensionales y la recorro con un foreach, pero no consigue que esta se muestre bien en la tabla necesito que se muestre correctamente "Muchas gracias por su atención"**

```
 $a  = array(
            'Ethan Winters',
            'Mia Winters',
            'Jack Baker',
            'Marguerite Baker',
            'Lucas Baker',
            'Zoe Baker',
            'Eveline',
            );
$b = array(

            'img/ethan.jpg'=>'Protagonita',
            'img/mia.jpg'=>'Contagiada',
            'img/jack.jpg'=>'Contagiado',
            'img/margue.jpg'=>'Congiada',
            'img/lucas.jpg'=>'Eveline no tiene control sobre el',
            'img/zoe.jpg'=>'Sana',
            'img/eveline.jpg'=>'Virus tipo E',

);
```

**Aquí es donde recorro mis arrays**

```
<tr>
    <th>Personajes</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php foreach($a as $per) { ?>    
    <?php foreach($b as $img=>$des) { ?> 
        <td><?php echo $per; ?></td>   

        <td><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" style="border-radius:8px;" width="200" height="200"></td>
        <td><?php echo $des; ?></td>

        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

[image: Esto sucede cuando lo ejecuto]

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes usar, solo si las posiciones de tus arrays están bien, es decir, si el elemento 0 del primer array debe ir con el elemento 0 del segundo array

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){ ?>    
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $a[$i]; ?></td>   
    <td><img src="<?php echo array_keys($b)[$i]; ?>" style="border-radius:8px;" width="200" height="200"></td>
    <td><?php echo array_values($b)[$i]; ?></td>
</tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar teniendo un solo array:

```
       $a = array(
                array('Ethan Winters', 'img/ethan.jpg', 'Protagonita'),
                array('Mia Winters', 'img/mia.jpg', 'Contagiada'),
                array('Jack Baker', 'img/jack.jpg', 'Contagiado'),
        );
```

y recorrerlo:

```
        <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Personajes</th>
            <th>Imagen</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <?php foreach($a as $fila) { ?>    
              <td><?php echo $fila[0]; ?></td>   
              <td><img src="<?php echo $fila[1]; ?>"></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[2]; ?></td>
             </tr>
            <?php } ?>
         </table>
```

Espero te ayude :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en este conjunto de lineas

```
<tr>
<?php foreach($a as $per) { ?>
```

Abres el tr antes del primer foreach, de manera que todos tienen un solo tr

Sustituyelo por

```
<?php foreach($a as $per) { ?>
<tr>
```

Por otra parte, desconozco el objetivo del por que usar dos foreach, te lleva a tratamiento de datos confusos, considera usar un solo array